# How to convert DensityMatrixMP object in PennyLane to a numpy array?

Tags: programming, pennylane

I am trying to get the density matrix from the Pennylane code [`qml.density_matrix([0])`](https://docs.pennylane.ai/en/stable/code/api/pennylane.density_matrix.html).

However, it seems that the return type is [`DensityMatrixMP`](https://docs.pennylane.ai/en/stable/code/api/pennylane.measurements.DensityMatrixMP.html) and there is not much I can do with this type.

Hence, I want to change this `DensityMatrixMP` to `numpy.array`, but I could not find a way to do that. Could anyone help me sort this out?

Comment: Hi @JiQing, this is an abstract type which is meant to be returned from a function representing a quantum circuit. You should be able to get a numpy array by `return`ing this from a quantum function and calling it. You can see an example of this in action in the docs page you linked.

Comment: Oh I see, I am asking the question because I cannot directly do the manipulation in the ```return``` function such as ```np.abs(qml.density_matrix([0]))``` because it will cause ```TypeError: absolute requires ndarray or scalar arguments, got <class 'pennylane.measurements.state.DensityMatrixMP'> at position 0.``` But I guess I could do the manipulation after ```return``` ing the density matrix. Thank you.

Comment: you're exactly right! That's how you're intended to do it